# how to get python matplotlib mathtext working on centos7/rhel7?

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos7, rhel7

On centos7/rhel7, I try to do a simple plot using an example from documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.arange(10))
plt.title(r'$\alpha > \beta$')
print plt.__version__
plt.show()
```

- `matplotlib.__version__` shows `1.2.0` (installed from RPM).
- `plt.rcParams['text.usetext']` is set to `False`

Instead of seeing the expected greek symbols for alpha and beta i see: `*©@`.

I don't want to install `latex`. I don't want to use anaconda python distro.

**how can I get matplotlib mathtext working on centos7/rhel7?**

p.s. I tried `plt.rcParams['text.usetext'] = True` but got a `sh latex command not found` error (`latex` is obviously not installed).

Comment: `from matplotlib import rc ;  rc('text', usetex=False)`

Comment: @gboffi i guess my written question is not clear. let me clarify. when i have `rcParams['text.usetex']` set to `False` that is when i get `*©@`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### in a nutshell, you can not use the RPM installed matplotlib --> instead use a pip install version (matplotlib version 2.2.x for python2, matplotlib version >= 3.x for python3).

- for centos7 builtin python2 matplotlib it is i think version 1.2.x and it is built without lots of feature
- most likely the python2 matplotlib is built without the math `tex` because that would significantly increase the complexity of packaging and significantly increase the software deps and so they went with a more minimal matplotlib